# Declining a call on iPhone 12 Mini (by pushing side button) while I'm on Zoom Meeting on iMac opens Music app and starts random music track

Tags: iphone, itunes, imac, music

I really had no idea how to name this question, yet it now describes my problem.

So I was over a Zoom call / meeting on my iMac with Bose headphones connected. Suddenly someone phoned me but I couldn't / didn't want to answer so I quickly grabbed my phone and pressed the side button several times.

It declined the incoming call **but also suddenly opened Music app on my iMac (not iPhone) and automatically started playing a random song**.

Where is this setup, how to stop it? It's very enigmatic and unnecessary.

Comment: Did your Bose headphones connect to your phone when you received the call?

Comment: Fantastic question - yes indeed. iPhone and Bose are paired and connected along with iMac. Please don't tell me that the easiest solution is to disconnect iPhone from the headphones. ;) I'm more interested in turning off that music autoplay…

Comment: It seems like your Bose headphones are sending a signal to play audio to your computer, after the phone call is ended. The computer is not automatically playing music just because the headphones are connected.

Comment: I use bluetooth headphones and I've never seen this - but if your headphones are trying to be smart about resuming the audio they might be inadvertently messing stuff up.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252280243 and https://www.reddit.com/r/bose/comments/jxwr0m/how_to_turn_off_the_apple_music_auto_launch_with/